# Can I divide two de-referenced pointers?

Tags: c++

Here is a sample from my code, I'm using visual studio , it gives and unhandled exception error:

```
    int *x=NULL;
    int *y=NULL;
    int z;
    int a =10;
    int b=2;
    x=&a;
    y=&b;
    z=*x/*y;
```

Comment: `z=*x/*y;` => `z=(*x)/(*y);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: How it compile in VS as **/*** is sart of comment section hence it will give compile time error.

Comment: Take a look at your post.  Do you see that the `*y` is grayed out on the last line?  That gives an indication of the problem.

Comment: Write your code with readability in mind (such as separating operator tokens from operands with white space) and this problem disappears.

Comment: Here's a tip for asking a question: if you ask about an error, describe the _specific_ error. This code doesn't produce an "unhandled exception error". It could only do that if it compiled and ran. But this doesn't compile at all because of the "comment unclosed at end of file" compile-time error. In fact it may even show a squiggly red underline below the part of the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: This should be one of the most upvoted posts!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note the `/*` in your last statement `z=*x/*y;`. In C or C++, `/*` stands for the begging of comment.

Here, in my Linux, g++ recognizes `/*` as a start of comment, but it can't find the end, hence it reports:

```
error: unterminated comment
```

To help the compiler distinguish this situation, simply insert a space between `/` and `*`:

```
z = *x / *y;
```

or use `()` to wrap each pointer dereference.

```
z = (*x)/(*y);
```

Comment: Yes, you should be putting spaces on either side of operators anyway, if you value readability.